# UPDATE & DELETE queries through Linked server in fails. But INSERT & SELECT works fine

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a Windows 2019 machine. I have SQL Server 2016. I have created a linked server & I am trying to execute some queries on a remote Db2 server. I am using MSDASQL provider, i.e. 'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers'.

The INSERT & SELECT queries work fine.

However the UPDATE & DELETE queries fail. For example, a DELETE query as shown gives the below error.

```sql
DELETE OPENQUERY (TEST2016, 'SELECT * FROM ABC.WORK_ITEM WHERE id = 123');
```

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 12.
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST2016" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 12.
> Cannot execute the query "SELECT * FROM ABC.WORK_ITEM WHERE id = 123" against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "TEST2016".

As I mentioned, if I run the SELECT query separately, as shown below, the query works fine.

```sql
select * from OPENQUERY(TEST2016, 'SELECT * FROM ABC.WORK_ITEM where wi_id = 123');
```

Am I missing any configuration/settings?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using a Linked Server query, such as `DELETE FROM TEST2016.ABC.WORK_ITEM WHERE id = 123;`

Comment: @Peter Smith, what permissions you are referring to?

Comment: @Charlieface, the same query works fine on Windows 2012 machine with SQL Server 2012. There are thousands of such queries & it is not possible to change queries in application at this time.

Comment: Found the issue. I had a new 2019 Windows on which the user was created with admin privileges. However some of the SQL Server related folders inside the Windows folder did not have relevant permissions. As a result, part of the code which was trying to access the folder was failing. After granting all the permissions, the issue got resolved.